# How do I mirror one side of an object to another side that's already there?

Tags: mirror

What would the best way to go around mirroring one side of an object to another already existing side?

Allow me to show the blend file. I need to copy the side with the holes to the side without the holes. https://a.pomf.cat/jqerzl.blend

edit: 
I am trying to cut a revolvers cylinder in half so I can mirror one side to the other, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Do you want the holes to pass from one side to the other (instead of the interior cone shape you have now? If you you would be better to extrude the one side to the other to create the bullet chambers all the way through.

Comment: Is it okay to change the object origin or do you need to keep it where it is?

Comment: I need to keep it where it is and the holes passing from one side from the other is the best. Thanks so much for answering, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to provide 2 solutions to this answer: mirroring the side with the cone shaped holes, and secondly extruding that side to give bullet chambers that pass all the way through. Feel free to use either option.

**Solution 1 - Mirrored Side Option**

[image]

1. Delete the duplicated object Drum.001
2. Enter edit mode on the Drum object
3. Change selection mode to Edge and select an edge that connects both side of the cylinder.
4. <kbd>Select</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> - Cursor to Selected (make sure you don't move the cursor after this step)
5. Select all the verts on the end that you are not keeping and delete.
6. Select all the verts on the other side that you want to mirror, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate
7. Press the <kbd>.</kbd> key to change the pivot type to Cursor
8. <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>-1</kbd> to scale along the y axis in the negative direction. This should copy your verts to the other side of the cylinder.
9. Select all, and Remove Doubles
10. Select all, and do Limited Dissolve (this is optional but it makes connecting the two side easier in the next step).
11. In edge select mode select the outer circle of both sides. Then <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and type Bridge to find the Bridge Edge Loops command.

**Solution 2 - Extruded Side**

[image]

1. Delete the duplicated object Drum.001
2. Enter edit mode on the Drum object
3. Change selection mode to Edge and select an edge that connects both side of the cylinder.
4. <kbd>Select</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> - Cursor to Selected (make sure you don't move the cursor after this step)
5. Select all the verts on the end that you are not keeping and delete.
6. Select the tips of the cones and delete. You should now have one face with 6 holes in it.
7. Select all, and Remove Doubles
8. Select all, and do Limited Dissolve (this is optional but it makes connecting the two side easier in the next step).
9. Press the <kbd>.</kbd> key to change the pivot type to Cursor
10. With all verts select press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
11. <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>-1</kbd> to scale along the y axis in the negative direction. This will move your extruded side to the other location giving you a full cylinder with 6 bullet chambers that pass all the way through.

Comment: By an edge that connects to both sides of the cylinder do you mean like this? http://puu.sh/pxcxI/d214f89acd.png

Comment: Any of the edges that connect between the 2 sides of the cylinder will work, just need it to find the centre point between the side.

Comment: How did you do the first selection? I can do everything else just not that haha

Comment: Switch to Edge selection mode. I'll add that to the steps.